# How do I return 1 if the first character of lastName is betweeen A and M and 2 if N through Z?

Tags: java

I need to Fix the getLineNumberFor method to return a 1 if the first character of lastName is between A and M or else return 2 if it is between N and Z.

Sounds easy in my head but I'm not sure what I'm suppose to be using here. Not sure if I was suppose to use charAt.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConferenceRegistration {


    /**
     * Assists in guiding people to the proper line based on their last name.
     *
     * @param lastName The person's last name
     * @return The line number based on the first letter of lastName
     */
    public int getLineNumberFor(String lastName) {
        int lineNumberOne = 1;
        int lineNumberTwo = 2;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        lastName = scanner.nextLine();
        char guess = lastName.charAt(0);

        if(lastName >= 'm'){
            return lineNumberOne;
        }
        else{
            return lineNumberTwo;
        }
    /*
      lineNumber should be set based on the first character of the person's last name
      Line 1 - A thru M
      Line 2 - N thru Z

     */

    }
}
```

Comment: Aside form main question there is no point in `lastName = scanner.nextLine();` since `lastName` is method *parameter*, so it should hold value passed when method was used. For instance when you call `getLineNumberFor("Adams")` `lastName` would hold `Adams` from which you can take first character with `charAt(0)` and do your testing. Assigning new value to `lastName` (and reading it from user without printing any info explaining informing user that he needs to provide some data) doesn't look right.

Comment: Fun fact: java `char`s are numbers: So you could, if you don't care about maintaining your code, do something like `((guess - 'A') / 13) + 1` - I don't recommend doing it, but you could.

Comment: Hint: Strings can be compared, case insensitively.   Also, you need to specify a locale for this kind of analysis. Otherwise, the user's Java implementation will pick one, perhaps based on their environment (or is that exactly what you need?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `chatAt(index)` to get the character you want to check, then for your condition you can use ternary operation like this :

```
public int getLineNumberFor(String lastName) {
    char c = lastName.charAt(0);
    return c >= 'A' && c <= 'M' ? 1 : c >= 'N' && c <= 'Z' ? 2 : 0;
}
```

Note that if no case is correct it will return 0 you can change it to any default value.

---

Or as @Pshemo mentioned in comment, using il else is more readable so you can change your code to be :

```
public int getLineNumberFor(String lastName) {
    char c = lastName.charAt(0);
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'M') {
        return 1;
    } else if (c >= 'N' && c <= 'Z') {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While it looks like valid solution I would run scared if I would see it at start of my programming curse. `if(conditionA){ return 1; } else if (condition2){ return 2;}` IMO is more readable than series of conditional operators.

Comment: Okay so help me understand this better if I am wrong. I didn't even need a Scanner class? I set variable char c to charAt(0) which would check the first string of the lastName. I return c if is equal or greater than A and if its less than or equal to M returning 1. I am guessing the : means else?

Comment: @Joshua Thao the else is the second part you mzntioned it in your question, ** and M or else return 2 if it is between N and Z.** and if no condition is correct you can return a default value or throw an exception if you want

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(guess <= 'm'){
```

This will let you compare just the first `char` in the `String`, since `>` and `<` comparison works fine on `char`s (since they can be compared basically like `int`), but is more complicated for `String`.

Note that it's **<=** not `>=` because for Java `char` `a < b < z`. See an [ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) for details. Furthermore, you'll need to add further logic if you don't want the user to enter "?" and get 1, or "-" and get 2.

Comment: As your linked page says, "Java actually uses Unicode". (Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and specifications agree.) I think that means don't use that table.

Comment: While it's true that Java characters are Unicode not ASCII, I don't think the distinction is the salient point here.  The point is that the OP's code has his comparison operators wrong.  The requirement is to return 1 for A through M; the code is returning 1 for characters greater than or equal to M (well, 'm', actually).  FWIW, less-than is wrong too. The requirement demands "less than or equal to M".

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to using comparison between `char`s would be to use a string with all letters to convert the first letter of the `lastName` to integer and compare the integers

```
class Test {

    private static final String LETTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static final int INDEX_OF_M = LETTERS.indexOf("M");

    public int getLineNumberFor(String lastName) {

        int indexOfFirstLetter = LETTERS.indexOf(lastName.toUpperCase().charAt(0));

        return (indexOfFirstLetter <= INDEX_OF_M) ? 1 : 2;
    }
}
```

(!) in this case is not really relevant as is only a simple example but using indexOf is more expensive than comparing `char`s. With such an approach the code is cleaner, though if performance is a concern then use comparison between `char`s

Comment: Ahh that would have made it easier for my eyes. Thanks for the advice!